# Sprite Image getting clipped/cropped in SFML window

Tags: c++, sfml

I'm using this book called "Beginning C++ game programming" to learn, well, game programming.
The following is a snippet from the book which display the background of the first game in an SFML window.
(Apologies for my use of namespace I'm just following the book).

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

using namespace sf;

int main() 
{
    RenderWindow window(VideoMode(1920, 1080), "Timber!!", Style::Fullscreen);

    Texture textureBackground;
    textureBackground.loadFromFile("graphics/background.png");
    Sprite spriteBackground;
    spriteBackground.setTexture(textureBackground);
    spriteBackground.setPosition(0,0);

    while (window.isOpen()) 
    {
        if (Keyboard::isKeyPressed(Keyboard::Escape)) {
            window.close();
        }
        window.clear();

        window.draw(spriteBackground);

        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The problem that I'm facing is no image I try in loadFromFile shows up fully in the window. It shows up zoomed towards the top left, even though I'm using the same window size as the resolution of the image.

Any help/advice is appreciated. Cheers!

EDIT: Added images

What I see:(Apologies for the bad picture my screenshot tool doesn't seem to be working when this is on)
[image]

Original image:
[image]

Comment: Either the picture is bigger than the window or you set its position in the wrong place

Comment: Actually, the pickture is okay from the repository from the book. The position is alright by the way. I believe that author should progress a bit further in the book.Or just copy a code from the repository and get the idea what is going wrong.

Comment: @NixoN I had considered that and gone on ahead. But further on in the next chapter they're adding more sprites and all the sprites seem to come up zoomed in on my PC.

Comment: Did you copy the code from the book or somewhere else? Because I completed this book and the timber game showed up okay. Try removing  Style::Fullscreen

Comment: @NixoN It's from the book itself. 2019 edition. 
I tried removing Style::Fullscreen. Same result.

Comment: I tried all the other styles too. Didn't work.

Comment: Any guesses on what the issue might be on my end then?

Comment: Does this only happens with a game from the book?

Comment: @KanishkaRakhecha are you sure that your laptop is 1920x1080 resolution? if it's lower, then you try to fit an image that is bigger than your screen, so just assign your true resolution in `VideoMode`

Comment: @AlexLarionov I have tried it with 1366x768 and even 800x600. Comes even more zoomed in.

Comment: @Kanishka Rakhecha BTW You cannot take screenshots because your program has no event handling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your laptop doesn't have a 1980x1080 resolution. Set the available resolution. Then change the [view](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/graphics-view.php) to fit the whole picture:

```
Vector2f textureSize(1980, 1080); // or texture.getSize()
VideoMode videomode(1980, 1080);
if (!videomode.isValid()) {
    videomode = VideoMode::getDesktopMode();
}

RenderWindow window(videomode, "Timber!!", Style::Fullscreen);
window.setView(View(FloatRect(0, 0, textureSize.x, textureSize.y)));
```